# Is it possible to pass an output parameter to the database with log4net's ADONETAppender?

Tags: database, oracle, logging, oracle11g, log4net

I have an output parameter in an Oracle stored procedure I use for logging (returns the number of rows affected - should be 1 if the procedure was successful). Note that I don't plan on using the return value from logging, but other procedures have it and it is utilized elsewhere, and I'm looking to not deviate from this pattern for the logging procedure.

However, I seem to be unable to:

1. Make the OUTPUT parameter optional in Oracle
2. Specify the parameter as an OUTPUT parameter type in the log4net configuration

The procedure is similar to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USERS.LOGS_INSERT
(
  p_Date IN DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  p_Source IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, 
  p_Host IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, 
  p_Level IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  p_Message IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  p_Stack_Trace IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  p_RowsAffected OUT NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO LOGS (LOG_DATE, LOG_SOURCE, LOG_SOURCE_HOST, LOG_LEVEL, LOG_MESSAGE, LOG_STACK_TRACE)
  VALUES (p_Date, p_Source, p_Host, p_Level, p_Message, p_Stack_Trace);

  p_RowsAffected := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      p_RowsAffected := 0;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      p_RowsAffected := -2;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      p_RowsAffected := -1;

END;
/
```

And the .config file contains:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
  <bufferSize value="1"/>
  <connectionType value="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <commandType value="StoredProcedure"/>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="p_Date"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="p_Source"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{application}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="p_Host"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="100"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="p_Level"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="50"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="p_Message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="p_Stack_Trace"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{stack}"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="p_RowsAffected"/>
    <dbType value="Int32"/>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: As far as "make the OUT parameter optional", you're correct - you can't do that. [See table 8-1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#i4107) and note that you **must pass a variable** to an OUT parameter. Also note that [you can only specify DEFAULT values for IN parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#i6821). Share and enjoy.

Comment: I see that, and categorize it in the numerous limitations I have in Oracle that I don't have in M$ SQL Server. Given this limitation, should the log4net configuration listed above be working with the procedure defined above? Shouldn't I be specifying that it's an OUTPUT parameter to log4net somehow?